# Show that function $f: A \to B$ is surjective when there is an implication: $g \circ f = h\circ f \to g=h$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Let $f: A \to B$. How can I show that $f$ is surjective if and only if (for every $C$ and every pair of functions $g, h: B \to C$) when there is the following implication?

$$
g \circ f = h\circ f \to g=h
$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For future references, the keywords are [right cancellable](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=right+cancellable+surjective+onto).

Comment: The keyword is also [epimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f$ is *not* surjective.

Then some $b\in B$ exists which is not in the image of $f$.

Now construct functions $g,h:B\rightarrow C$ s.t. $g(x)=h(x)$ if $x\neq b$ and $g(b)\neq h(b)$.

Then $g\circ f=h\circ f$ but $g\neq h$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a constructive proof.

- Let $B' = \{ b \in B : \exists a \in A . f (a) = b \}$, i.e. $B'$ is the image of $f : A \to B$.
- Let $C = \mathscr{P} (1)$, i.e. the set of subsets of the one-element set $1 = \{ 0 \}$.
- Let $g : B \to C$ be the function $b \mapsto 1$.
- Let $h : B \to C$ be the function $b \mapsto \{ x \in 1 : b \in B' \}$.
- Observe that $B' = \{ b \in B : h (b) = 1 \}$; indeed, $\{ x \in 1 : b \in B' \} = 1$ if and only if $b \in B'$.
- For each $a \in A$, $g (f (a)) = 1$ and $h (f (a)) = 1$, so $g \circ f = h \circ f$.
- But $f : A \to B$ is right cancellable, so $g = h$.
- Hence, $B' = B$, i.e. $f : A \to B$ is surjective.

Comment: I'm not sure the definition of the function $h$ is clear. At least I am not parsing it.

Comment: It's an application of the axiom of separation. The only funny thing is that $x$ does not appear on the RHS, but that's allowed.

Comment: Essentially. Go back to the axiom of separation: we have $x \in h (b)$ if and only if $b \in B'$. Of course, $h (b) \subseteq 1 = \{ 0 \}$, so it comes down to $0 \in h (b)$ if and only if $b \in B'$. If $b \notin B'$ then $0 \notin h (b)$, so $h (b) \ne 1$.

Comment: Sorry for the deletion of the comment. I tried to edit it and failed. At any rate, one could be clearer about it, for the sake of the OP, perhaps? There is a big amount of people not familiar with the more formal set theory.

Comment: +1 It is a nice construction. I hope it is not beyond the reach of the OP.